# Taylor on $h$ smooth

Tags: integration, derivatives, stochastic-processes, taylor-expansion, markov-chains

I'm struggling to proof that

### $\int_{\mathbb{R}}P(z,t|x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D^{(n)}(z)h^{(n)}(z)dz$

(with $D^{(n)}(z):=\frac{1}{n!}\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}P(y,\Delta t|x)(y-z)^{n}dy$ and $P$ transition density of an Ito's process) is equal to

### $\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(z)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^{n}[D^{(n)}(z)P(z,t|x)]dz$

I know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D^{(n)}(z)h^{(n)}(z)dz\equiv \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})^{n}[D(z)h(z)]dz=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}D^{(n)}(z)h(z)+h^{(n)}(z)D(z)$

but I'm having a hard time to understand how apply Fundamental Theorem of integral calculus in this case. I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try integration by parts: if $fg$ vanishes at infinity then we have $\int f g' = -\int f'g$ so by repeated application of this (if some conditions on $f,g$ are met) then you can show that $\int f g^{(n)} = \int (-1)^n f^{(n)} g$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for answer. If $(n)=1$ I know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}[D'hdz]=Dh-\int_{\mathbb{R}}Dh'dz$ but I don't understand how to apply integration by parts at infinity. Can you please show me all passages what I should do?

Comment: For definite integration it reads $\int_{a}^b D'h = [Dh](b) - [Dh](a) - \int_a^b Dh'$. If now $b$ is infinity then $[Dh](b) = \lim_{x\to\infty} [Dh](x)$ or informaly "$Dh(\infty)$". I would expect the transition density to vanish at infinity and if so then $[Dh](b) - [Dh](a) = "[Dh](+\infty) - [Dh](-\infty)"$ would vanish.

Comment: @Winther Thanks again. Ok, I understood your reasoning but in the integral that I want to obtain continues to be $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$... Really, I've been thinking about you said but I still can't derive the result. Furthermore, for what reason $P(z,t|x)$ has been included in parenthesis?

Comment: Use $\int \sum = \sum \int$ then do integration by part on each of the integrals in the sum (which requires you to assume some conditions on the functions involved for this to hold). Each integral is $\sum \int \left[P D^{(n)}\right] h^{(n)}$ so if we set $f = \left[P D^{(n)}\right]$ then it's $\int f h^{(n)}$ which can be transformed into $\int (-1)^n f^{(n)}h$. This is why $P$ has to be included.